# AudioInputStream.getFrameLength returns incorrect length

Tags: java, audio, libraries

I was trying to get duration of **audio** files in Java.

I wrote this code (with some help of stackoverflow):

```
public static Duration getDuration(File file) {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 
    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
    long frames = audioInputStream.getFrameLength();
    double durationInSeconds = (frames) / format.getFrameRate();
    return Duration.ofSeconds(Math.round(durationInSeconds));
}
```

And I added some audio libraries in pom file to be able to get the correct audioInputStream (*com.googlecode.soundlibs.basicplayer*).

However, the **audioInputStream.getFrameLength is returning a -1** value always when I try to load some mp3 from my classpath.

Did someone had the same problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, It worked with the following code

```
public static Duration getDuration(File file) {
    val audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
    val fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);  
    long frames = fileFormat.getFrameLength(); // I get the frame length from file format, not InputStream
    val format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
    double durationInSeconds = (frames) / format.getFrameRate();
    return Duration.ofSeconds(Math.round(durationInSeconds));
}
```

Internally getAudioInputStream should do this, but it was not working so I had to do it myself.

Comment:  Only way I've found that actually works

Comment: This does not work when e.g. listening to microphone instead of reading a file.